Google Drive - lost connection when uploading a file
I've created a new Google email address which provides you with a free 15GB of Google Drive storage.
However, whenever I try to upload any kind of file to the Google Drive storage it always throws out a "connection lost" message and does not upload the file.
I've noticed that this issue is quite common but I couldn't find any workaround to fix my problem with this.
If you have any ideas or have encountered a similar issue, could you please share them?
Thank you!

uhh, are you using the google drive api or a browser?

browser, google chrome, I  just noticed it autofiled the tag, will edit it :)

first, try a different browser (e.g. edge). if that helps, maybe you have some sort of CORS extension installed on chrome?

I tried MS Edge and getting the same behavior...no, I don´t have any CORS extension either...
it is really frustrating

hmm, try installing google drive for PC? see if you can upload files from there? also try Firefox? it is certainly weird, we'll try to debug it together, although stack overflow isn't really the community for this issue

try using a different network but same device, if possible. (and of course, same network different device)

another thing I didn't mention is that I'm using not my personal but corporate laptop. It seems it has something to do with that, with VPN. I shared the Google Drive with my personal Gmail and tried to upload from my phone (different network, different device), and I was able to upload files...
But... when using my phone and trying to upload a picture via Google Forms, which is linked to the google drive storage, it still does not work.

I resolved it on my end by disabling the CORS Unlock extension.
